# Compare and replace values among multiple columns using a vectorized code in R

Tags: r

I can find many questions about conditionally replacing values of a (or multiple) column(s) based on a threshold value.

However, what I want to solve is to replace the smaller (or larger) value with a specified value.
For example, in the `swiss` dataset, I want to compare the last two columns (i.e. Catholic and Infant.Mortality) and replace the smaller value with 999 for each row.

```
>   swiss[1:5, c(ncol(swiss), (ncol(swiss) - 1))]
             Infant.Mortality Catholic
Courtelary               22.2     9.96
Delemont                 22.2    84.84
Franches-Mnt             20.2    93.40
Moutier                  20.3    33.77
Neuveville               20.6     5.16

<some code I want to write>

### the expected result
             Infant.Mortality Catholic
Courtelary               22.2     999
Delemont                 999    84.84
Franches-Mnt             999    93.40
Moutier                  999    33.77
Neuveville               20.6     999
```

I guess I can use `for` statement or other looping methods (e.g. row-wise `apply`) to do the comparison and replacement.
However, I will deal with a mega-size data (e.g. hundreds of millions of observations) so I want to find a way to do it rapidly (e.g. vectorized one).

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the minimum index for each row, create a row/column matrix and replace it with 999.

```
df[cbind(1:nrow(df), apply(df, 1, which.min))] <- 999
df
#             Infant.Mortality Catholic
#Courtelary               22.2   999.00
#Delemont                999.0    84.84
#Franches-Mnt            999.0    93.40
#Moutier                 999.0    33.77
#Neuveville               20.6   999.00
```

If `apply(df, 1....` is too slow you can use `max.col`.

```
df[cbind(1:nrow(df), max.col(-df))] <- 999
```

**data**

```
df <- swiss[1:5, c(ncol(swiss), (ncol(swiss) - 1))]
```

Comment: Thank you! Doesn't `cbind` slow down the running?

Comment: Nice @Ronak! I was trying something like this: `ifelse(df[, 1] > df[, 2], df[, 2] <- 999, df[, 1] <- 999)` but it is not replacing the values back into `df`. Could this work with some adjustments? (The `df` is the same as in your answer, and even if this is not quicker than your suggestion, could it be modified to work?)

Comment: I haven't done any testing on large data but usually, it is slow when you `cbind` data in a loop or something. Here we are doing it only once.

Comment: @KJM `ifelse` will not directly work since we need to conditionally apply a value in one column or the other.